# Merge my accounts

Tags: support, status-completed, user-accounts

Can you merge this account 
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/9635/sevki to this https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/1567/sevki account dear moderator

Comment: By probably deleting the latter one and adding that open-id to the one thats mentioned first....

Answer (score 1):

Done! You can put a new OpenID in your remain account.

Answer (score 0):

As neither profile has any associated questions or answers it will be simpler to just delete the one you don't want.

Can you edit the profile of the one you want to delete so I get the right one.

Once that's done you can add the second OpenId as the alternate id to the remaining profile.

Comment: just did it.....